# Doesn't work with the code datetime.strptime in python

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

I want to convert datetime string to datetime format.
I already tried with datetime.strptime but this code doesn't covert to datetime format.

In python 3.0 version, I tried strptime and parse to covert to datetime format.

```
nut_time_ = (nut_unique_date + ' ' + nut_unique_time)

print(nut_time)

nut_time_ = datetime.datetime.strptime(nut_time_, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

print(nut_time)
```

The format that I want to get is :
datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 6, 20, 33, 42)

But the actual results is :
2013-01-06 20:33:42

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick answer:

```
print(repr(nut_time_))
```

The issue is whether you want to `print(str(nut_time_))` or the `repr` version. The former is what you get. So nothing wrong with you. The latter is what you usually see in the Python REPL. If you use `print()` function to print some stuff, by default it will give you the str representation.

Comment: Then how can I make like this? 2013, 1, 6, 20, 33, 42 Is it already covert to that format? I plan to calculate the two different datetime duration, so I need that format.

Comment: To convert to a format: `print(nut_time_.strftime("%Y, %m, %d, %H, %M, %S"))`, or read the datetime manual to extract each items you want (if you find the difference, the object is called timedelta)